# MySQL: Get data from other table matching the ids

Tags: php, mysql

I have table named 'company' and 'user'. The user table contains the id of company.
Like for example:

```
A. User table

user_id | name | company_id |status
1       | john |    1       | active

B. Company table

company_id | name | status
1          | ABC  | active
```

How to get the name of the company by their id in single sql query.
such;

```
$query = "SELECT name as Username, company_id as Company_Name From `user` where status='active'";
```

That will give the result of:

```
Username | Company_Name
  john   | ABC
```

Any help or ideas on how to do this...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT u.name AS Username, c.name AS Company_Name
FROM User AS u
INNER JOIN Company AS c
  ON u.company_id = c.company_id
WHERE u.status = 'active'
  AND c.status = 'active'
```

Feel free to remove either or both of the expressions in the WHERE clause if they don't make sense.

Comment: Thanks anyway.. but i have found my own sql. 
SELECT u.name AS Username, (SELECT c.name FROM Company as c WHERE c.id=u.company_id) as Company_Name FROM user as u WHERE u.status = 'active'

Comment: I'd stick to Ignacio's answer: he's using a join which is far more efficient than your double-query solution.